# AppCenter not installing updates

Tags: appcenter

The [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) does not install updates. And when I used the terminal to update it gave me this:

```
sudo apt update  
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                                   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Fetched 102 kB in 2s (46.0 kB/s)                              
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I am not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Also, I am not quite sure why when I use the Shift key to change cases, I have to push the key I want twice.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out a that I just needed to do the command it told me to. Wow what a surprise!

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

fixed everything.

I still have the problem with the shift key though.

Comment: Please accept your answer as **answer**.