# Package manager blocked

Tags: updates, appcenter, package-management

Since I had no answers writing in Portugese, I'll try to translate my problem to English.

I am trying to update the system and some apps via AppCenter (I guessing the name of the store like application, since my system language is Portuguese) but every time I got the same answer:

**"Waiting for the package manager block"**  (trying to translate the message).

And then I can't update anything, neither the system or the apps.

This happened after I tried to install the latest updates but it was taking a very long time to finish (like 2 hours) and then I had to shut down the computer, but I couldn't because of the updating process. So I had to force shut down. After that, I always get this message when I try to install any update.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could manage the situation.

I found a guy with the same problem and the solution was very simple, just had to do what the system was telling me to, when I tried to update via terminal.

[App centre not installing updates](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/app-centre-not-installing-updates)

The command line to fix the problem was that:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Hi Levy, this is an english speaking community. Please answer in English, so people can understand your answer. Thanks!